# No error description provided though QSqlQuery::exec fails

Tags: c++, qt

I get into the if block:

```
if ( !_query.exec( ) )
    {
        QString errdb = _db.driver()->lastError().databaseText();
        QString errdrv = _db.driver()->lastError().driverText();
        //...
```

but errdb and errdrv are empty.

Is there another way to check what went wrong?

Comment: `_query.lastError()` ?

Comment: @m.s. Thank you very much! Was using wrong function. Want you write it as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the error using [QSqlQuery::lastError()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#lastError), in your case `_query.lastError()`.

Quote from the Qt documentation:

> Returns error information about the last error (if any) that occurred
>   with this query.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `_db.lastError().text()`.

Comment: No, it didn't help. Apparently, the QSqlQuery errors are not conveyed to QSqlDatabase, even is the query is done on that DB-instance. The solution from m.s. works: _query.lastError().

Comment: Oh. Good to know that you found the solution. Happy that even I got to learn something new! :)